# Change color of a owl-carousel image

Tags: css, colors, slider, owl-carousel, grayscale

I have 3 images in an owl-carousel slider, and have used

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

CSS tags convert all 3 color images to grayscale, but what I want is, when the slider runs every 2th image it should be shown in its native colors. [Please see the attached sample for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ7tQ.jpg)

I have tried several ways, but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to catch the center slider on the owl-carousel.

Answer (score 1):

I solver this issue in this way
CSS:

```
.owl-item.center img{
  -webkit-filter: none; 
   filter: none;
 }

.owl-item img{
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

JS (the center: true is the key):

```
 var owl = $('.main');
      owl.owlCarousel({
        margin: 0,
        center:true,
        nav: true,
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        dots: true,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:1500,
        autoplayHoverPause:true
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to follow OWL's "center" example.

Link here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

When you configure your carousel like this the item in the center is assigned the class `center`.

[image: center class screenshot]

You can assign your css filter to `.owl-carousel .center img` or `.owl-carousel .center` depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the the active elements will have `active` class appended to it. And you can use this CSS

```
.owl-item.active:nth-child(2) .item img {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Since you have 3 items, the second child will always the greyscale.